# DataSet and XmlDataDocument

Tags: .net, mysql, database, dataset

What is the importance of using XMlDataDocument with dataset. It is getting me bit confused
Can some one please explain the importance of this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN:

> XmlDataDocument has a close affiliation with the DataSet class, which provides a relational view of the loaded XML data. Any changes made to the XmlDataDocument are reflected in the DataSet and vice versa.

So essentially, the reason you would use XmlDataDocument is to **strongly link** your xmldata with the dataset. This doesn't mean you need to, or have to use it. Also be aware that this class seems to be **obsolete in .Net 4.0**.

Go here for some [more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

i have founded a link i explain a lots..

http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/03/31/xmldatadocument.html